# Flutter: Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's location

Tags: flutter, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

i am trying to get user current location in flutter but its showing map, but not pointing my current location. I have added all required permissions in AndriodManifest file.

here is snap

[image]

here are the logs

```
I/Google Maps Android API(24140): Google Play services package version: 201817022
E/GoogleMapController(24140): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
D/HostConnection(24140): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xefab0ec0, tid 25110
E/flutter (24140): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's location.
E/flutter (24140): #0      MethodChannelGeolocator._handlePlatformException
package:geolocator_platform_interface/…/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:242
E/flutter (24140): #1      MethodChannelGeolocator.getCurrentPosition
package:geolocator_platform_interface/…/implementations/method_channel_geolocator.dart:124
E/flutter (24140): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24140): #2      _locationState.locatepostion
package:map_app/abc.dart:26
E/flutter (24140): <asynchronous suspension>
W/System  (24140): A resource failed to call release.
```

code

```
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap=Completer();
  late GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;
  double mapbottompadding=0;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldkey=new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late Position currentpositon;
  var geolocator=Geolocator();

  void locatepostion() async{
    Position position=await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentpositon=position;  // this is line 26, it is point before await

    LatLng latLngPosition=LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition=new CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition,zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  }

  static final CameraPosition googlepostion=CameraPosition(target: LatLng(37.4249,-122.0657));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        GoogleMap(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: mapbottompadding),
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
           initialCameraPosition: googlepostion,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
              _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
              newGoogleMapController=controller;
              setState(() {
                mapbottompadding=300.0;
              });         
              locatepostion();
```

and here is my output

[image]

**-------Update**

it's working perfectly on andriod phone, but not working on emulator.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
 LocationPermission permission;
   permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
```

request for the permission first by using this.

Answer (score 16):

```
class GeolocatorService {
  Future<Position?> determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
        return Future.error('Location Not Available');
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception('Error');
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a common issues in [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) that arises esp. when you don't grant permission to the device. By default it is disabled, so you have to request for it when the `locatePosition()` is called. Remember that the geolocator package is wrapped under [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter).
So to solve the location problem, ensure you do the following

```dart
class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
void locatePosition() async {
    bool isLocationServiceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    
    await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    
    currentPosition = position;
    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        
    // Ask permission from device
    Future<void> requestPermission() async {
    await Permission.location.request();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this follow the below steps:

1. add permissions to respective platforms.

- **Android**: Project->android->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml
  add permission inside the  tag
  "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION />"
- **IOS**: Project->ios->Runner->Info.plist
  add permission inside the  tag
  "<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>"

2. Call method on click of your button

   void getLocation() async{
   LocationPermission permission;
   permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
   print(position);   //here you will get your Latitude and Longitude
   }

This solution worked for me, Hope it would helpful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Please also check your permission request.
For example: Your permission status is under this button; "Find my location"

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
          PermissionStatus location = await Permission.location.request();
          locationInfo();
        }, child: const Text("Find my location")),
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem while working on a udemy project [clima_flutter](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/Clima-Flutter)

Was getting below errors while launching the app

```
Flutter: Unhandled Exception: User denied permissions to access the device's location
```

My flutter version is 3.16.9

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

And my dart version is 3.2.6

```
  dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6 (stable) (Wed Jan 24 13:41:58 2024 +0000) on "macos_x64"
```

The gradle wrapper version I am using is 7.5

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

Using below dependency for geolocator

```
geolocator: ^11.0.0
```

Was trying to load current location at the app startup.

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();
  }
```

Where getLocation calls the getCurrentLocation() method

```
Future<void> getLocation() async {
    await Location().getCurrentLocation();
 }
```

Pre-Requisite:

For android below permissions request should be added in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And for ios, in ios/Runner/info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
```

Still my code was failing. And below implementation is a fix. Where we first check if the permission is available, if not then we request before hand.

```
Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        print("No permission, requesting one");
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
          return Future.error('Location Not Available');
        }
      } 
        print("Found permission to get location");
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
        latitude = position.latitude;
        longitude = position.longitude;
      
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

With this implementation a request dialog was prompted on the emulator to provide the location permission.